# Can an artificer heal a homunculus servant at range?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

In the official version of artificer, the ability to create a homunculus servant is gained at 6th level. Among its other abilities, the homunculus can:

> **Channel Magic** The homunculus delivers a spell you cast that has a range
>   of touch. The homunculus must be within 120 feet of you.

Further:

> The homunculus regains 2d6 hit points if the mending spell is cast on
>   it

*Mending* has a range of touch. Is there any reason an artificer cannot use the spell to repair his homunculus servant so long as it is within 120 feet?

Comment: If you're asking about the official version, you shouldn't link to the UA version. That will only confuse the issue.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson, Okay, I rolled back the link.

Comment: @NathanS The only official 5e artificer is from Eberron: Rising from the Last War, so the question is presumably asking about: https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#HomunculusServant (No page numbers because I don't own the physical book)

Comment: @Ryan Yes, you are right. Thanks for that. Also, your comments on the deleted answer now clear up my initial confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, the homunculus can channel a *Mending* spell to itself

Since *Mending* has a range of touch, it can be delivered through the homunculus using its Channel Magic ability. And [the rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range) explicitly call out that touch-range spells can target the caster (or in this case, the deliverer):

> Some spells can target only a creature (including you) that you touch.

Hence, the homunculus can use its Channel Magic ability to deliver a *Mending* spell cast by its master to itself.

Comment: Only the Homuculus of an Artificer is not as powerful as the one in the MM.

Comment: That's why it is called a "homunculus servant" in its statblock and not a "homunculus". WotC should have been consistent in the rest of the entry however, to prevent confusion.

Comment: Too bad Mending takes a minute to cast.